# Problems with running docker-compose

Tags: apt, python, docker

`docker-compose` is not found and I can't install it via `apt`. How to solve this problem?

```
$ docker-compose
bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory

$ sudo apt install docker-compose
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
docker-compose is already the newest version (1.21.0-3)
```

if you ask "How did I end here?" - I used to have the following problem:

```
$ docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
  ...
ImportError: No module named ssl_match_hostname
```

And in an attempt to fix this I executed these commands:

```
sudo -H python -m pip uninstall docker docker-compose
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install docker docker-compose
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following link to read the installation instructions directly from Dockers documentation.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

It looks like you are missing a few of the dependencies and it looks like you have to check your path or create a symbolic link to get the `docker-compose` command to work. The following lines are directly from the documentation

```
Note: If the command docker-compose fails after installation, check your path. You can also create a symbolic link to /usr/bin or any other directory in your path.

For example:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Also, you should be installing "docker-ce" and not the outdated "docker" package with apt.

Use this link to find the instructions on how to install the correct `docker-ce` package

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: For security reasons and for system stability, generally it's not a good idea to install software from websites, especially if the community already packaged this. We are currently working around the underlying root problem: the underlying environment was probably broken by the user.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, try creating another Unix user, and try from that user.

If it works, probably your local Unix user has broken Python libraries in the `.local` directory.

Try finding your `.local` directory:

```
ls -l ~/.local/lib | grep python
```

Then try disabling it. Example:

```
mv ~/.local/lib/python3.8 ~/.local/lib/python.bak
```

I hope this could help, since it's very frequent for users to destroy their local Python environment using pip or other things that can affect your specific Unix user.

In this way you should get a clean Python environment, well-tested from Ubuntu package administrators. So, the official `docker-compose` package provided by Ubuntu should just work again.